# glXGetFBConfigs is causing huge amounts of memory to leak

Tags: opengl, memory-leaks, valgrind, xcb, glx

I have the following call to `glXGetFBConfigs`:

```
const GLXFBConfig * fbuf_configs = glXGetFBConfigs (
    display, screen_id, &fbuf_config_count
)
```

Upon inspecting it with *valgrind*, it produces 137 loss records for a function `dlopen_doit`, which subsequently calls a `malloc`. Below is an example of one such record, however all 137 are essentially uniform, such that `dlopen_doit` is the culprit.

```
==12317== 9 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 16 of 137
==12317==    at 0x483579F: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12317==    by 0x6B1FB5B: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.435.21)
==12317==    by 0x6B19F54: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.435.21)
==12317==    by 0x6B11934: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.435.21)
==12317==    by 0x6B2337F: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.435.21)
==12317==    by 0x58145B5: ??? (in /usr/lib64/opengl/nvidia/lib/libGLX_nvidia.so.435.21)
==12317==    by 0x400F29B: call_init.part.0 (in /lib64/ld-2.29.so)
==12317==    by 0x400F3D8: _dl_init (in /lib64/ld-2.29.so)
==12317==    by 0x40131E2: dl_open_worker (in /lib64/ld-2.29.so)
==12317==    by 0x4DC5F90: _dl_catch_exception (in /lib64/libc-2.29.so)
==12317==    by 0x4012AD9: _dl_open (in /lib64/ld-2.29.so)
==12317==    by 0x4E5529B: dlopen_doit (in /lib64/libdl-2.29.so)
```

I am unable to find any information on-line regarding `dlopen_doit`, and the manual page for `glXGetFBConfigs` is hardly extensive, and does not mention any need to manually free its return value. I only was able to discover that `glXGetFBConfigs` was the cause by slowly isolating all other function calls, as it is mentioned nowhere in the *valgrind* trace.

What is the cause and potential solution for such behaviour ?

Comment: "and does not mention any need to manually free its return value." glXGetFBConfigs" allocates the list it returns and you have to free it when youa re done with it. See https://sources.debian.org/src/mesa/19.2.1-1/src/glx/glxcmds.c/?hl=1658#L1658. But that does not involve `dlopen()` and thus is not an answer to your question.

Comment: Can you run your program again under valgrind with a higher value for `--num-callers` so that the stack trace is longer? Let's say, `--num-callers 100`.

Comment: Oh and: Why is this tagged `xcb`? Are you using xcb in your program somehow, or what?

Comment: @UliSchlachter Yes, I'm using xcb. I apologise if I should have not included it as a tag, I wasn't sure if it was directly relevant to the issue. Thank you for your link to the implementation; freeing the memory does alleviate a very small amount of the leaks. I'll run Valgrind with a higher stack trace and edit my question very soon.

Comment: After some digging through call traces and the _glibc_ source, it seems that these are almost certainly false positives. Each `_dl_open` and `_dl_init` has a subsequent `_dl_close` and `_dl_close_worker` according to _callgrind_. Not entirely sure on why _valgrind_ is missing these, but at least I can assume it safe to suppress these "errors".

Comment: Not false-positives.  These are leaks.  I'm seeing this as well in my own programs. In my case, the callers higher in the callstack point to glfw.

Comment: Run your program like so:
`valgrind --num-callers=100 --leak-check=full ./myprogram`

Comment: @010110110101 Are you absolutely sure ? As I said in my previous comment on Oct. 28, after inspecting the source code of the internal `open` and `close` calls, I confirmed with callgrind that every object that was opened and malloc'd had a subsequent free.